# declaring user function with default non-value parameters

Tags: php, function

At declaring user function with default non-value parameters, what way is better, define parameters as `false` or as `NULL` ?
that is,  what is better, this

```
 function func ($param = false) {

 }
```

or this

```
 function func ($param = NULL) {

 }
```

?

Comment: That would depend on what `$param` is supposed to indicate. Is it a default boolean as in `$auto_commit` or an optional value? Too speculative.

Answer (score 5):

This would be better:

```
function func ($param = NULL) {

}
```

A "default non-value" parameter should be NULL, not `false`. False is a value. If you intend to test the parameter for its value or perform any operation on/with it, I would go with `false`.

Comment: It's stated somewhere in the PHP manual that values that could stay empty should be set to NULL. (But I can't find the source right now…)

Answer (score -1):

We can also use

```
function func ($param = "") {
```

}